# installing/upgrading tensorflow 2 on windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I ran below command after opening `cmd` with admin rights. I currently have tensorflow `'1.15.0'` and my python is `3.7.3` and my pip is `pip 19.3.1 from c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`

1. should i upgrade `grpcio`?
2. do I need to worry about warnings in the update 2 below?

Error messages are

```
**ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 has requirement grpcio>=1.24.3, but you'll have grpcio 1.24.0 which is incompatible.**
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-estimator, scipy, tensorboard, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow-estimator 1.15.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-estimator-1.15.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-estimator-1.15.1
  Found existing installation: scipy 1.2.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.2.1
**ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\nnn\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~cipy\\fftpack\\convolve.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.**
```

the command that i ran -

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/d5/ce8c17971067c0184c9045112b755be5461d5ce5253ef65a367e1298d7c5/tensorflow-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (355.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 355.9MB 9.7kB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast==0.2.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.2.0,>=2.1.0rc0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/90/b77c328a1304437ab1310b463e533fa7689f4bfc41549593056d812fab8e/tensorflow_estimator-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (448kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 450kB 939kB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.33.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/51/046cbc61c7607e5ecead6ff1a9453fba5e7e47a5ea8d608cc7036586a5ef/scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (30.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 30.9MB 2.2MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.24.0)
Collecting tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/23/53ffe290341cd0855d595b0a2e7485932f473798af173bbe3a584b99bb06/tensorboard-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.8MB 1.6MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.8.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
**ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 has requirement grpcio>=1.24.3, but you'll have grpcio 1.24.0 which is incompatible.**
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-estimator, scipy, tensorboard, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow-estimator 1.15.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-estimator-1.15.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-estimator-1.15.1
  Found existing installation: scipy 1.2.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.2.1
**ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\nnn\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~cipy\\fftpack\\convolve.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.**
```

----------------update 2

I tried running same command with `--user` option and also updated `grpcio` and i get below message. The error message is at the bottom. Do i have to activate conda enviroment to use tensorflow 2? cannot i used directly in windows as I had used used previous versions or tensorflow?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade grpcio --user
Collecting grpcio
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/14/ab1501cfff78b88d7368659b227c603d7599dd25226ff682c71334e78aed/grpcio-1.26.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.8MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 139kB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from grpcio) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: grpcio
Successfully installed grpcio-1.26.0
```

then

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade tensorflow --user
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in c:\users\nnn\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast==0.2.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.8.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorflow-estimator<2.2.0,>=2.1.0rc0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0 in c:\users\nnn\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.33.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\nnn\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.8.0->tensorflow) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\nnn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
```

The error message --------->

```
C:\Users\nnn>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\nnn\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\nnn\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\nnn\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\nnn\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\nnn\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: try running it in an admin cmd prompt?

Comment: thats what i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to activate the anaconda environment?

```
C:\Users\nnn>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

.....    
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

based on the Conda documentation:
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

> You may receive a warning message if you have not activated your environment:
>
> Warning:
>   This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
>   not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment
>   please see https://conda.io/activation.
>
> If you receive this warning, you need to activate your environment. To do so on Windows, run: c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base in Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: I havent, but cannot i use TF2 directly in windows as I had used used previous versions of the tensorflow?

Comment: As you installed a new Library it may require an update of the conda environment to add the new Library(s) and dependencies. I've seen other posts about missing DDL's but they were related to the TF2-GPU and CUDA compatibility/installation (e.g https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35618)

Comment: Thanks for the link. `pip install tensorflow==2.0` worked for me.

Comment: Glad to know! I thought that would help.